# MYSQL - Select row even if row does not join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys

I am trying to find one query that returns all people including the company they belong to and companies that do not have any person assigned yet.

**Company**

```
cid | cname
--------------
1     Company 1
2     Company 2
```

**Person**

```
pid | pname     | fk_company
---------------------------
1     Person 1    1
2     Person 2    1
```

**desired result**

```
pid | pname    | fk_company | cid | cname     
----------------------------------------------
1     Person 1   1            1     Company 1
2     Person 2   1            1     Company 1 
NULL  NULL       NULL         2     Company 2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us your attempt(s), we don't do your work for you. Hint: use `LEFT JOIN`. [ask]

Comment: So start with `Company` and `LEFT JOIN` the others. By the way, you may need to use `FULL JOIN` if you want both all companies and all persons.

Comment: If I would have any solution that is close to what I want, then I would have included it. But I don't. With a simple left join(SELECT * FROM person LEFT JOIN company ON person.fk_company = company.cid) I get all people including the company they belong to but then I miss the companies that do not have a person assigned. So I guess I need to add another join but I can't figure out its conditions. With a cross join, I get quite a lot of results.Well I could later sort them out but I think that will need quite a lot of performance. I am hoping that there is an elegant solution that I can't see...

Comment: Thanks a lot! SELECT * FROM company LEFT JOIN person ON person.fk_company = company.cid does the job. I don't know why I didn't see it... I really stucked on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want everything from both tables, regardless of match left AND right, you need a FULL JOIN:

```
SELECT    * 
FROM      person 
FULL JOIN company 
       ON person.fk_company = company.cid
```

**edit**: Apparently mysql doesn't support `FULL JOIN`. You'll have to do both `LEFT JOINS` by hand and `UNION ALL` them.

Answer (score 0):

You should mention something you tried. Anyway, I will explain the method so you can work on it.

```
SELECT <column_names>FROM <table1_name> LEFT JOIN <table2_name>ON 
<table1.column_name> = <table2.column_name>;
```

For more explanations please refer this link.
[SQL Left Join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)